# vbscript Eval a string to a Variable in a loop?

Tags: string, variables, vbscript, eval, execute

I am trying to use vbscript's Eval (or maybe I need Execute) to create some variables from the key names from an ini file. The ini file can have unlimited unknown key=val pairs. I need to create a variable based on the key name no matter what.

Ini File contents:

```
myPath=c:\test
myExe=myapp.exe
....
xxx=123
yyy=abc
```

My code that reads the ini and returns the key and values to an object

The code I am trying to get working is here:

```
For each pair in objINI
    Eval("pair.key=pair.val")
Next

msgbox myPath
msgbox myExe
```

But both msgbox's are showing empty
And yes I am sure pair.key and pair.val have the correct values.

Thoughts on what I am missing or if this is even possible?

Comment: I think you need to re-evaluate your architecture.  Having an ini file that can set any variable it wants sounds...unsafe.

Comment: How it looks in my example isn't how it will actually work. There is no risk.

Comment: `eval` and risk are synonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You eval'd the literal code `pair.key = pair.value`.
That assigns to `pair.key`.

You want to assign to the *value* of `pair.key` – if `pair.key` is `myPath`, you want to eval `myPath = pair.value`.
You can do that by concatenating strings:

```
Execute(pair.name + " = pair.value")
```

Comment: But I don't know that "myPath" will be my keyname. I need to generate the variables dynamically based on the key names from the file. My ini file might have "myPath".. another guy might call it "xPath" .. in the end, I will need to use msgbox myPath, and he will need to use msbox xPath

Comment: @Dss: Exactly.  You need to concatenate the string to eval.

Comment: @SLaks -1 for mixing Eval and Execute[Global].

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean SLaks.. Concatenating strings doesn't seem to be relevant here. I am simply trying to convert a string into a variable. The pair.key is the full name of the variable-to-be. I think I need something like a Double Eval that will first eval the pair.key to a string, then eval that to be set as a variable to the pair.value

Comment: YES! Thanks ... I see what you mean now by concat. Working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `Execute` (an assign statement), not to `Eval`(uate a boolean expression):

```
>> n = "Name"
>> v = "Value"
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(Eval("n=v"))
>>
Boolean
>> Execute "n=v"
>> WScript.Echo n
>>
Value
>>
```

From the docs:

> In VBScript, x = y can be interpreted two ways. The first is as an
>   assignment statement, where the value of y is assigned to x. The
>   second interpretation is as an expression that tests if x and y have
>   the same value. If they do, result is True; if they are not, result is
>   False. The Execute statement always uses the first interpretation,
>   whereas the Eval method always uses the second.

(This does not mean you should do such things; neither at home, nor at work)

Comment: Ah ok thanks for clarifying.. I kept trying eval and execute but kept mixing up which was doing what. Got it working using this info and SLaks answer below

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read key/value pairs from an INI file you'd be better off storing them in a dictionary. I wrote a [function](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/parseini.shtml) for this some years ago. Basically looks like this:

```
Function ParseIni(filename)
  Set ParseIni = Nothing

  Set config = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  section = ""

  Set file = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(filename)
  Do While Not file.AtEndOfStream
    line = Trim(Replace(file.ReadLine, vbTab, " "))
    If InStr(line, ";") > 0 Then line = Trim(Left(line, InStr(line, ";") - 1))
    If line <> "" Then
      If Left(line, 1) = "[" And Right(line, 1) = "]" Then
        ' line is a section name
        section = Trim(Mid(line, 2, Len(line) - 2))
        If section = "" Then _
          WScript.Echo "Parse Error: section name is empty string."
        If config.Exists(section) Then _
          WScript.Echo "Parse Error: duplicate section name '" & name & "'."
        config.Add section, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
      ElseIf InStr(line, "=") > 0 Then
        ' line is a parameter line
        If section = "" And Not config.Exists(section) Then _
          config.Add section, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        param = Split(line, "=", 2)
        param(0) = Trim(param(0))
        param(1) = Trim(param(1))
        If param(0) = "" Then _
          WScript.Echo "Parse Error: invalid parameter name '" & param(0) & "'."
        If param(1) = "" Then param(1) = True
        config(section).Add param(0), param(1)
      Else
        ' line is neither parameter nor section name, thus invalid
        WScript.Echo "Parse Error: expected parameter definition in line '" _
          & line & "'."
      End If
    End If
  Loop
  file.Close

  Set ParseIni = config
End Function
```