# Pass a string as a variable name QTP

Tags: vbscript, parameter-passing, eval, qtp, execute

I have a function that does the same operation for all of my scripts, but only the variable in which the Pass-Fail value  is stored, would change.
For example, in one script -> the status is stored in Envrionment.Value("Current_Status")
in another script -> the status is stored in DataTable.Value("Status",1)
in another script -> the status is stored in objRS("AddCriteria_Status").Value

So i am trying to make a function in which i pass on these parameters as strings and then later use them as variable names. Here is the sample code:

```
Envrionment.Value("Current_Status") = "none"
Environment.Value("Fail_text") = "none"
Call AddCriteria("Environment.Value(""Current_Status"")","Environment.Value(""Fail_text"")")

Pubic Function AddCriteria(varStatus,varActual)

varTemp = ""

Execute(varStatus+ "=InProgress")    'change status to InProgress by the time execution is done
Execute(varActual + "=not_defined")   'this will have the reason the case failed

....code

If varTemp = "FAIL" Then
 Execute(varStatus+ "=PASS")
 Execute(varActual + "=PASS")
Else
 Execute(varStatus+ "=FAIL")
 Execute(varActual + "=Criteria did not get added")
End If

End Function
```

On calling the sub-routine i want the value of Environment.Value("Current_Status") to change from "none" to "InProgress" and then to "PASS"
But after the "Execute" command is executed, the Environment variable become empty.

Since CVar is not supported in VBScript, i cannot use it.

I tried Eval, but it doesn't work in the other direction i.e.:
If you change the value of Environment.Value("Current_Status"), then the value Eval(varStatus) changes, but I could not find a way to change the value of Eval(varStatus) so that the value of Environment.Value("Current_Status") changes.

Please help out. I am stuck at this for a week.

!!!What I'm trying to accomplish!!!

In a .vbs file, pass on any string to a function as a parameter; and convert it into a variable name in that function. Simple example: pass a string "abc" as a parameter to a function -> and within that function, convert the string to a variable name to store value [say, abc = "PASS"]

!!!How I attempt to do it!!!

I tried using Execute command as that is a solution that I got from a previous post
[[vbscript Eval a string to a Variable in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947241/vbscript-eval-a-string-to-a-variable-in-a-loop])

Using "CVar" is a way but that is not supported in VBScript. So I ran out of ideas

!!!Problems that I faced!!!

Honestly, I didn't understand the logic of using "Execute", but i tried it nevertheless. Sadly, it didn't work out. When using execute command (as mentioned in the code), the environment variables become empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideas:

- Use `ExecuteGlobal` to execute the assignment you want to execute --
  if that´s what you want. `Eval` and especially `Execute` have subtle limitations regarding the scope they live in.
- The target variable (i.e. the variable that receives a value in the
  assignment that is evaluated by `ExecuteGlobal`) must be a *global*
  variable.
- If the `ExecuteGlobal` call happens on an Action's global scope, the
  target variable must be declared there, too. (I *think*.)
- If the `ExecuteGlobal` call happens in a routine in a function
  library, the target variable must be declared there, too. (*I know that for sure.* But read on.)

To further help you, I'd need an update on your question because it is not clear what you want to accomplish, and what problems you see. Because -- `Eval` does not change values, it just evaluates an expression supplied as a string, and returns its value. If the expression has side-effects, like setting a global variable, then you might be out of luck because...well...it depends on where that global variable is declared, and initialized (if at all), and where the ExecuteGlobal call happens. **Actions and libraries do NOT share one global scope, even if it looks like they do, and that can create a lot of strange behavior.**

But as I said, if you clarify what you are trying to accomplish (got 90% of that), how you attempt to do it (got 40% of it), and what problems you face (got 10% of it), I´m sure I can update this answer so it approaches a solution.

** Update **

I use this library code for all runtime expression evaluation, be it from within a library or Action:

```
' Interpret (execute) a piece of VSH source code consisting of statements -- success?
'   Code: String containing VBS source code. Passed by reference for performance reasons only
Public Function ExecCode (ByRef Code)
    Dim ErrNumber
    Dim ErrDescription

    On error resume next ' Avoid getting kicked out by errors in the code contained in Code
    ExecuteGlobal Code
    ErrNumber=Err.Number
    ErrDescription=Err.Description
    On error goto 0 ' Re-enable RTE handling

    If ErrNumber <> 0 Then
        ExecCode=false

        Print "Code execution failed ('" & ErrDescription & "'), code:" & vbNewline & Code & "<eof>"
    else
        ExecCode=true
    End If
End Function

Dim GlobalVar

' Interpret (execute) a piece of VSH source code consisting of a single expression -- success?
'   Expr; String containing a VBS expression. Passed by reference for performance reasons only.
'   Target: Variable receiving the value to which the expression evaluates
Public Function EvalCodeAndAssign (ByRef Expr, ByRef Target)

    ' In order to force "Option explicit", we don´t use Eval, but ExecCode (and thus ExecuteGlobal):
    Dim Code: Code="Option Explicit: GlobalVar=(" & Expr & ")"
    Dim Result: Result=ExecCode (Code)
    If Result Then
        Target=GlobalVar
    End If
    EvalCodeAndAssign=Result

End Function
```

Update 2: if the statement that you pass to ExecuteGlobal contains quotes (which I think are missing in your code), the must be quoted, I.e. you must use double-quotes, like in

```
ExecuteGlobal "x=""This is a string"""
```

Because what ExecuteGlobal/Execute/Eval do is: take a string and interpret it as VBScript code. **The code you are trying to use is not valid due to missing quotes.**