# How to dynamically name VBScript variables inside for loop?

Tags: vbscript

How can I declare and then assign variables dynamically in an iterative loop.  For example:

```
for i = i to some_number
    dim "prefix" & i
    "prefix" & i = 2 * i
next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim MyArray(5)

For x = 0 to 4
    MyArray(x) = 2 * (x + 1)
Next

For each thing in MyArray
    Wscript.echo thing
Next

For x = 0 to 4
     wscript.echo MyArray(x)
Next
```

If you don't know how many a dictionary is usually easier. It you have two or more items it is easier. From Help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object

```
Dim d                   'Create a variable
Set d = CreateObject(Scripting.Dictionary)
d.Add "a", "Athens"     'Add some keys and items
d.Add "b", "Belgrade"
d.Add "c", "Cairo"
```

Also to make them from text.

```
MyArray1 = Split("This is a bunch of words", " ")    

For each thing in MyArray1
    Wscript.echo thing
Next
```

Comment: This approach might work but the OPs request is dynamically assigning variables which would use the [Duplicate approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947241/vbscript-eval-a-string-to-a-variable-in-a-loop) of `Execute` and `ExecuteGlobal`. To be honest, there isn't a lot of information to go off in the question.